# Is there a way to know whether previous month is clicked or next month in PrimeNG calendar?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG calendar v9 in my angular 9 application. I am using multiple months with an inline calendar. Now, I need to know whether the user is navigating ahead in time or in the past by clicking the month navigation button. Is there a way to know? I have searched everything but unable to get the answers.

```html
<p-calendar (onMonthChange)="onMonthChange($event)"
            (onSelect)="getScheduleData()"
            [(ngModel)]="calDate"
            [inline]="true"
            [locale]="en"
            [numberOfMonths]="3"
            [showWeek]="false">
  <ng-template let-date pTemplate="date">
    <span (click)="dateClicked(date)"
          [contextMenuSubject]="date"
          [contextMenu]="dateRtClickedMenu"
          [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: getDayColor(date)}"
          [title]="getTooltip(date)"
          style="border-radius:10%; display:block;">
      {{date.day}}
    </span>
  </ng-template>
</p-calendar>
```

Comment: why don't you do that in `onMonthChange`?

Comment: because `onMonthChange` will not tell me what months(showing multiple months) are being displayed on screen, and I need to fetch data based on the months visible on screen.